# Karma + Jasmine Testing setup breaks the ionic packaging

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, jasmine, karma-runner

I have an ionic app and I introduced testing using karma + jasmine. Also I use a typescript pre-processor for my tests.

I have the following dependencies, where all but the first two had to be added for testing:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "1.0.0",
    "typescript": "2.0.9"

    "@types/core-js": "^0.9.35",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.41",
    "angular-cli": "^1.0.0-beta.26",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.5.2",
    "karma": "^1.4.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.0",
    "karma-safari-launcher": "^1.0.0",
    "karma-typescript": "^2.1.6",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.9",
  },
```

`tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es2015"
    ],
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5"
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "atom": {
    "rewriteTsconfig": false
  }
}
```

This is my `karma.conf.js` file:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ["jasmine", "karma-typescript"],
    files: [
      {pattern: "src/**/*.spec.ts"},
      {pattern: "test/**/*.spec.ts"},
      {pattern: 'node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js', included: true, watched: true}
    ],

    preprocessors: {
      "**/*.ts": ["karma-typescript"], // *.tsx for React Jsx
    },

    reporters: ["progress", "karma-typescript"],

    port: 9876,

    colors: true,

    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,

    autoWatch: false,

    browsers: ['Safari'],

    singleRun: true,

    concurrency: Infinity
  })
}
```

#### The problem

Now the testing works fine using the command:

```
./node_modules/karma/bin/karma start karma.conf.js
```

But when I now run `ionic serve` I get really cryptic error messages like so:

- > Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type. Variable '[Symbol.unscopables]' must be of type '{ copyWithin: boolean; entries: boolean; fill: boolean; find: boolean; findIndex: boolean; keys: ...', but here has type 'any'.
- > Typescript Error
  >   All declarations of 'name' must have identical modifiers.
- > Typescript Error
  >   Duplicate identifier 'PropertyKey'.

My take is that the devDependencies mess up the "load path" for the rest of the app. So I wonder how I get my app to work again.

Comment: This is probably due to two .d.ts files conflicting each other, could you post your tsconfig.json? I think that `@types/core-js` is responsible. Are you sure you need it? Because it seems that it is conflicting with the `lib.es6.d.ts` of TypeScript.

Comment: @fathyb: Thanks for your input I did update the question.

Comment: Thank you, the problem is that you are using es2015 definitions with core-js definitions. Core-JS provides polyfills and thus is conflicting with TypeScript standard definitions. Try to replace es2015 with es5, if you get even more errors just try to put es2015 again and remove @types/core-js.

Comment: Removing the core-js from the package.json did not fix the problem. The errors were still the same. Then I replaced es2015 with es6 and target=es5 with es6 (There is three occurrences so I don't know if I did that right), but that did not solve the problem either.

Comment: `es5` is not an option at all: `Argument for '--module' option must be: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es6', 'es2015' 
`

Comment: @fathyb: I was wrong. Removing core-js did solve the problem. If you add this as an answer I'll happily accept it. Now when I run the tests I get a lot of errors like this: `node_modules/@angular/common/src/directives/ng_class.d.ts(46,34): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.`

Comment: Great! It cannot find `Set` because of the `lib` compiler option, is it still `es2015` ? And I think you had the error with `es5` because you've changed the `module` option and not the `lib` one (I should have told you).

Comment: @fathyb: It's just a warning and the tests run well otherwise. But the tests are compiled using the karma-typescript component so I don't see the options there. The rest of the project still uses `es2015` like before.

Comment: ok I found why, it's because Karma-Typescript tsconfig.json uses es5 by default, I'm not familiar with Karma but I think you can add `karmaTypescriptConfig: { compilerOptions: { lib: ['dom', 'es2015'] } }` to your karma.conf.js

Comment: @fathyb: Brilliant! If you like add an answer and I will happily accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `es2015` definitions with `core-js` definitions.

Core-JS provides polyfills and thus is conflicting with TypeScript ES6+ standard definitions.

Remove `@types/core-js` and add `karmaTypescriptConfig: { compilerOptions: { lib: ['dom', 'es2015'] } }` to your `karma.conf.js` to make Karma-Typescript use `es2015` definitions.